# Registered pre(post) operation callback not called on specific computer in Minifilter drive

Tags: minifilter

I'm testing MiniFSWatcher(https://github.com/CenterDevice/MiniFSWatcher) on Windows 10 computers. And I've found MiniFSWatcher is not working properly on a specific computer. So I've left a DbgPrint in the callback functions both SpyPreOperationCallback and SpyPostOperationCallback at the top of the functions. But when I check with DbgView, the logs not showed up. Default messages in MiniFSWatcher showed up, though. It seems, somehow, the callback functions not called in a specific computer. And every Flt functions in DriveEntry return success code 0. What things can cause this kind of problem?

The problematic computer's spec is below.

- CPU : AMD Ryzen 1700
- RAM : DDR4 32GB
- HDD : 256G SSD, 4TB HDD
- OS : Windows 10 64bit Build No. 15063.332

Please reply me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. It was because Minispy driver and MiniFSWatcher are watching different drive. In other words, Minispy was watching h:\ and MiniFSWatcher was watching c:. I hope my case helps to someone.